# Reactjs pass value as prop after setState not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I'm trying to pass down to a modal a object via a prop when a user clicks to open. I'm receiving the value from the clicked row but my modal can't read the value from `this.props` and I'm getting an undefined. I am setting the state value correctly and passing it to the modal component.

**Modal Call**

```
<Modal toggleModal={this.toggleModal} show={this.state.isOpen}
          onClose={this.toggleModal} user={this.state.user} />
```

**Setting the state value**

```
toggleModal = (user) => {
var userData = {};
if (user !== null) {
  userData = user
}
this.setState({
  isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
  user: userData
},()=>{
  console.log('User data changed');
})
}
```

**Inside the render part of the modal component**

```
if (this.props.user === null) {
  userFound = 'Not found'
}
console.log(this.props.user);
```

When inside the modal component I get undefined. Everywhere before that I get the user object.

Thanks

Comment: try to `forceUpdate()` after the `setState()` has finished: `this.setState({
  isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
  user: userData
},()=>{
  console.log('User data changed'); this.forceUpdate();
})`

Comment: you are checking only null what is `user=undefined`, because `null !== undefined` is true, do `console.log(user)` inside toggleModal method and check the value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I still get an undefined when I pass the value to the Modal component.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your component you are just checking for null and not `undefined` , if you want to check for undefined one of the ways is to make use of `typeof`

`typeof user !== "undefined"`

so it will be like (You can ammend it accordingly if you want to check for both or one ):

```
toggleModal = (user) => {
  var userData = {};
  if (typeof user !== "undefined" && user !== null) {
  userData = user
}
```

And you can move `this.setState` inside if `block`

```
toggleModal = (user) => {
    if (typeof user !== "undefined" && user !== null) {
      this.setState({
        isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
        user: user
     })
    }
}
```

Comment: This part helps, however when inside the modal component I still get an undefined error, as if the `this.props.user` fails when it should have a user object.

Comment: this is because when setState is async action , Can you show where you are initialising your state i.e `this.state = {}`

Comment: I'm calling the forceUpdate() when the user data is set as suggested on this thread. Inside App.js I have `constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        isOpen: false,
        dataType: 'user',
        user: {}
    }
    this.changeSearchState = this.changeSearchState.bind(this);
  }`  Do I need to have a state on the modal component if I'm just using the props value?

Comment: I can see the user object when I .log from App.js -> but it comes back as undefined when called `this.props.user` from the modal component.

Comment: inside your modal component , can you .log `this.props` and see if you have wired up props correctly ? And if possible can you update your code with entire modal component instead of just `toggleModal`

Comment: Found it, Nested component issue! The modal component had some child content and I wasn't passing the user object down the chain. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad its sorted !